# unicode Error while adding ppa to ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, apt

I recently installed ubuntu 17.04 and when I tried to add a ppa, it gave this traceback stating some unicode error("label empty or too long") relating to idna.py, if it helps my internet runs on proxy

I entered the following command:

```
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa
```

and recieved following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 358, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 94, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 112, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1253, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 694, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 864, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 430, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 387, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 370, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 327, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 112, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1253, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 694, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Comment: You need to give more information to let us truly help you. What do you mean by "ppa"? Do you mean [Personal Package Archive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA)? What software are you instalign from that archive?  What does their support site say about installation errors?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a Unicode problem or a Python problem. It looks like an error in the PPA.

But you need to give more information to let us truly help you.  For instance, which PPA are you installing? Has it installed successfully on another system?

Comment: I was adding ppa:numix/ppa

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to add the details on which PPA you are installing, an a link to its description.

Comment: This is the case with every other ppa